# Accessing Local Storage in azure

Tags: pdf, azure, cloud, local-storage, azure-role-environment

I have a website in azure which I want to create pdfs from templates. I need some where to store the pdf while I'm creating it.  After some searching round I thought the best way to handle this would be through Local Storage. I added a Windows azure cloud service project to my web app. I then added local storage to the role for my web app. Locally I can now create pdfs from templates and store them in blob storage. However when I publish the app to azure it no longer works. I thought I might need to create a cloud service in azure from my local cloud service project so created a package to do this. The cloud service is now running but I still can't access local storage.

The line:

Dim myReportsStorage As LocalResource = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("myReports")

works locally but fails when I publish the website to azure. I'm not sure if I somehow need to link my website and my cloud service in azure but I can't see how to do this.

If anyone can help with this I would be very grateful.

Comment: That looks correct, assuming that the local storage is set up properly in your project configuration. It would be helpful if you would say what error you're getting.

Comment: Thanks for replying, it's good to know I'm heading in the right direction. I've now tracked down the error and it is "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime, Version=1.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.". I have referenced that in my web app so what else do I need to do?

Comment: I've done some more investigation and found that a page error is triggered if "Dim myReportsStorage As LocalResource = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("myReports")" appears in the Page_Load code. The page error occurs and the Page_load event doesn't even start.

Comment: Check the reference to that DLL, and make sure Copy Local is set to True.

Comment: Thanks, that's got me a bit further. The page now loads but still fails at the line "Dim myReportsStorage As LocalResource = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("myReports")". This time the error is "The type initializer for 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment' threw an exception." I've set my cloud service up for remote access and can see the myReports folder when I connect in. So the storage is there.

Comment: I've now solved that error by adding a reference to msshrtmi. However I'm now getting problems with that. and am getting a "could not load file or assembely msshrtmi" error. I've tried the x86 and x64 versions and setting copy local to both true and false. All with no luck. Any ideas what I can try next?

Comment: All sorted now. I hadn't set up my cloud service correctly. I've now followed the instructions at: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/cloud-service-with-sql-database/ and all works well.