# Writing and Reading to Local Storage in Azure WebJobs

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-web-app-service

I need to use local storage in an Azure WebJob (continuous if it matters). What is the recommended path for this? I want this to be as long-lasting as possible, so I am not wanting a Temp directory. I am well aware local storage in azure will always need to be backed by Blob storage or otherwise, which I already will be handling.

(To preempt question on that last part: This is a not frequently changing but large file (changes maybe once per week) that I want to cache in local storage for much faster times on startup. When not there or if out of date (which I will handle checking), it will download from the source blob and so forth.)

Related questions like [Accessing Local Storage in azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675343/accessing-local-storage-in-azure) don't specifically apply to a WebJob. However, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20615289/where-to-save-extract-files-on-azure-web-sites) is vitally connected, but 1) the answer replies on using `Server.MapPath` which is a System.Web dependent solution I think, and 2) I don't find this answer to have any research or definitive basis (though it is probably a good guess for the best solution). It would be nice if the Azure team gave more direction on this important issue, we're talking about nothing less than usage of the local hard drive.

Here are some Environment variables worth considering, though I don't know which to use:

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory: D:\local\Temp\jobs\continuous\webjobname123\idididid.id0

[PUBLIC, D:\Users\Public]
[ALLUSERSPROFILE, D:\local\ProgramData]
[LOCALAPPDATA, D:\local\LocalAppData]
[ProgramData, D:\local\ProgramData]
[WEBJOBS_PATH, D:\local\Temp\jobs\continuous\webjobname123\idididid.id0]
[SystemDrive, D:]
[LOCAL_EXPANDED, C:\DWASFiles\Sites\#1appservicename123]
[WEBSITE_SITE_NAME, webjobname123]
[USERPROFILE, D:\local\UserProfile]
[USERNAME, RD00333D444333$]
[WEBSITE_OWNER_NAME, asdf1234-asdf-1234-asdf-1234asdf1234+eastuswebspace]
[APP_POOL_CONFIG, C:\DWASFiles\Sites\#1appservicename123\Config\applicationhost.config]
[WEBJOBS_NAME, webjobname123]
[APPSETTING_WEBSITE_SITE_NAME, webjobname123]
[WEBROOT_PATH, D:\home\site\wwwroot]
[TMP, D:\local\Temp]
[COMPUTERNAME, RD00333D444333]
[HOME_EXPANDED, C:\DWASFiles\Sites\#1appservicename123\VirtualDirectory0]
[APPDATA, D:\local\AppData]
[WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID, asdf1234asdf134asdf1234asdf1234asdf1234asdf1234asdf12345asdf12342]
[HOMEPATH, \home]
[WEBJOBS_SHUTDOWN_FILE, D:\local\Temp\JobsShutdown\continuous\webjobname123\asdf1234.pfs]
[WEBJOBS_DATA_PATH, D:\home\data\jobs\continuous\webjobname123]
[HOME, D:\home]
[TEMP, D:\local\Temp]
```

Comment: How frequently does it change?

Comment: Is this a continuous job?  Are you running multiple instances in parallel that will all be checking for updates?

Comment: Thanks guys, I updated to answer the questions, but in short: 
File changes like maybe once a week.
Web Job is continuous: Yes (though would it matter?).
Multiple instance: Not now (though would it matter?).

Comment: If your batch size is greater than 1, I was just thinking about potential locking issues within a single web VM and if multiple threads check and try to update the file simultaneously.

Comment: Updating of the file in local storage would only occur from this singular webjob (nothing else would use this file). So multiple instances of the webjob wouldn't matter, each webjob would only ever write to it's own local storage (each instance is always on a different machine I believe). The backing blob is a different matter, but this webjob only reads that blob, it doesn't write it (something else does that which is out of scope to this question). Thanks.

Comment: You have write permissions to the root of the Web App. You can store it there.

Answer (score 2):

Using the %HOME% environment variable as a base path works for me nicely. I use a subfolder to store job-specific data, but other folder structure on top of this base path can be valid. For more details take a look at https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system and https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/File-structure-on-azure